# Android adding a Marker to a Map, if i hard code the lat/long it works, if i use return methods it always places the Marker on the equator

Tags: android, google-maps

First of all, sorry for the long title but i tried to be as descriptive as possible!

My problem is as follows:

I am trying to add Markers to my GoogleMap inside a SupportMapFragment in my Android application. I am able to add Markers, but the position they get placed is incorrect. The strange thing is that if i hard code the values the Marker gets placed in the correct position, but if i use return methods to return the position i want to place the Marker at the Marker always get placed roughly in the center of the equator (i assume this is a default).

**It must be noted, i have stepped through the de-bugger in eclipse several times, and the return methods p.getLongitude() and p.getLatitude() do in fact return the correct values so i can safely rule out the possibility of incorrect return types, Also my position are correct in the manifest**

code in question :

```
PointOfInterest p = data.getExtras().getParcelable("POIObject");

                Toast lol = Toast.makeText(context, p.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                lol.show();
                pois.add(p);
                addPOIToMap(p);;
                Toast x = Toast.makeText(context, "POIS SIZE " + pois.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                x.show();

    public void addPOIToMap(PointOfInterest p){

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(p.getLattitude()), Double.valueOf(p.getLongitude())))
        .title(p.getName())
        .snippet(p.getDescription())
        .draggable(false));
        Toast test = Toast.makeText(context, "Marker lat : " + p.getLattitude() +" lng : " + p.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        test.show();
    }

}
```

The "test" Toast, does in fact display the expected values so the return types are correct. The above code will place a marker in the center of the map on the equator.

The below code will place a Marker in the specified location:

```
public void addPOIToMap(PointOfInterest p){

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(47.13), Double.valueOf(4.89))
    .title(p.getName())
    .snippet(p.getDescription())
    .draggable(false));

}
```

Will n fact place a marker at 47.13, 4.89. So why is harcoding the latLng different to using return values which are in fact valid?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: When you examined the results of your `Double.valueOf()` calls, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare it told me that the values were 51.52 and 4.08?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, Google maps requests that the Lat and Long are reversed so swapping them should fix your issues.

This also happens when an invalid number is entered(lat > 90 or < -90)